# Slick Carousel Variable Slide Width

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

My question is how would you go about setting a percentage width for a individual slide in slick carousel? Currently, it sets a pixel value. I have tried setting a percentage width and it uses the parent of .slick-track which is 25000px wide which in turn makes the width of each slide massive.

To reiterate, I am trying to find the best way to set a percentage value to each slide of 25%. I want for slides to display and when you click on the next arrow it will slide in 4 more.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You are looking for the setting `variableWidth` that you must set to `true` if you want slick to use your css to customize your slides' width. You can see an example at their [doc page](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) if you search "Variable Width".

Comment: Awesome thank you!